# Does tf.strided_slice have a default stride of 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm trying to replicate the [Tensorflow tutorial for LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent), and in [reader.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py) there's a function called `ptb_producer` which produces the batches.

In that there's this:

```
i = tf.train.range_input_producer(epoch_size, shuffle=False).dequeue()
x = tf.strided_slice(data, [0, i * num_steps],
                     [batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps])
x.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps])
y = tf.strided_slice(data, [0, i * num_steps + 1],
                     [batch_size, (i + 1) * num_steps + 1])
y.set_shape([batch_size, num_steps])
```

Now on the [API page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice) for the function `tf.strided_slice`, it says the parameter `strides` has a default value of `None`. However, as you can see, there is no parameter for strides passed here. Meaning the default value will be used. Does this mean it takes a stride of 1 by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the default stride is 1. But with the newer TF versions it's better to write it this way:

```
x = data[0:batch_size, i * num_steps:(i + 1) * num_steps]
y = data[0:batch_size, i * num_steps + 1:(i + 1) * num_steps + 1]
```